# Unable to set correct localhost URL for Facebook webpage in developer console

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

Since last week I am unable to test my OAuth login using facebook because of this troubling bug - I am unable to set correct site url using localhost. When I'm trying to use this address:

```
http://localhost:9000/
```

inside developers.facebook.com settings I receive info:

> we're sorry but something went wrong

And my changes aren't saved. I am able to use localhost address with "www" prefix, but obviously it doesn't work for my app since I need to use bare "localhost" with port. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that sometimes Facebook has problems with generated apps' settings. After deleting application and creating another one, I was able to correctly set website URL to `http://localhost:9000`. It looks that it was indeterministic behavior.